# Creating Regex for a file name (python)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am strugling at creating a regex expression for my python program.

I need to test if the files in a folder are following this format:

> TvShowName.SxxExx.Title.fileextension

Where "SxxExx" means Season *number* Episode *number*

For example:

> **Dexter**.*S01E01*.**The Monster**.*mp4*
>
> **The Mentalist**.*S03E05*.**Red Lay**.*mp4*

Can someone help me "generalize" this filenames so I can test them?

Thank you

Comment: I am using this website: https://pythex.org/ but everything I time doesn't work. Never worked with regular expressions so complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, using named capturing groups:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'(?P<name>[^.]+)\.S(?P<S>\d+)E(?P<E>\d+)\.(?P<title>[^.]+)\.(?P<ext>.*)')
>>> r.search('Dexter.S01E01.The Monster.mp4').groupdict()
{'ext': 'mp4', 'title': 'The Monster', 'E': '01', 'S': '01', 'name': 'Dexter'}
>>> r.search('The Mentalist.S03E05.Red Lay.mp4').groupdict()
{'ext': 'mp4', 'title': 'Red Lay', 'E': '05', 'S': '03', 'name': 'The Mentalist'}
```

Regex explanation: http://regex101.com/r/gG9nK2